# ZSH browse content of zip file

Tags: zsh, zip

Is there any way or plugin for zsh where I can browse content of zip files in place instead of unzipping zip file and than making zip again?

I want to achieve same behavior as in Midnight Commander one can browse content of zip files without extracting them.

Many thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean with "and then making zip again"? I presented a zsh solution to browse the contents and display files from an archive -- IMHO a modification of a zip'd file with the midnight commander is also not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocompletion can "look" into archives. To display the content of a file you can use the `-p` parameter of `unzip`, which prints the decompressed file to stdout.

As a demonstration I zipped the source code of zsh itself into an zip archive:

```
$ unzip -p zsh-src.zip zsh-5.0.5/M[TAB]
file from archive                                    |  autocompletion!
MACHINES     Makefile.in  META-FAQ     Misc          |
$ unzip -p zsh-src.zip zsh-5.0.5/MACHINES | head
-----------------------------
ZSH ON SPECIFIC ARCHITECTURES
-----------------------------

These are the OSes that zsh has been tried on.  If you succeed in getting
zsh to work on an OS not listed, let us know.  The information in this
list may be out of date, as the developers do not have access to all
machines.  In general, GNU/Linux distributions, Solaris and Cygwin are
reasonably well covered.  Please let us have any recent information
on other systems.  The information for systems not known to have been
```

This also works with tar archives, e.g. using

```
$ tar xOf zsh-5.0.5.tar.bz2 zsh-5.0.5/MACHINES | head
```

where the file inside the archive of course gets autocompleted, too.

Answer (score 0):

Regular `unzip` command should not delete the original *.zip* file. It is strange that this is how it behaves for you.
Half of your solution is to modify your *unzip* command so that it does not delete the original *.zip* file after extracting.

Looking around I have not found a ability for *zsh* to do that. However, I did find this question that should be useful to you: [How to mount a zip file as a file system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94649/how-to-mount-a-zip-file-as-a-file-system)